# Determining if a stochastic process forms a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I believe this is a simple problem but im not sure if im satisfied with my solution.

We are tossing a fair coin. Let $X_n$ be the number of heads thrown in the $n+1$ and $n+2$ throw. Does the sequence $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ form a Markov chain.

My solution is a simple observation that $X_n$ does not satisfy the Markov property, wich means that when we are in state $n$ we have to know the states $n +1 $ and $n + 2$ in order to determine $X_n$.

Is my reasoning correct? How could I argue rigorously that $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ does not form a Markov chain?

Comment: I am sure you must know of a "rigorous" definition of a Markov chain. If you tell me what the definition is, I can give you a strategy.

Comment: My reference material is Rick Durrett's Essentials of Stochastic Processes. The definition of a Markov chain given is on page 5 and states: Markov chain with transition matrix $p(i,j)$ if for any $j, i, i_{n-1}, ..., i_0$ $$P(X_{n+1} = j \mid X_n = i, ..., X_0 = i_0) = p(i, j)$$.

Comment: Write the Markov property, “rigorously”. Then just ask yourself: Let this a “fair” tossing, ensuring a “random” walk, then how step $X_{n+3}$ to depend upon $X_{n}$? PS: Careful, Markov chain is not Markov property.

Comment: thank you, i will try to prove it this way.

Comment: Assume that $X_n$ is a Markov chain. Try and calculate values of $p(i,j)$ using small values of $n$. You'll find that just going up to $n=1,n=2$ and perhaps $n=3$, you will find that $p(i,j)$ cannot be defined uniquely.